# drupal 7 CORS localhost ajax request

Tags: html, jquery, drupal-7, cross-domain, cors

im trying to pull data from drupal 7 website from a local files inside

http://example.com:8888/test/test.html

im using this Ajax code with html request since i have tried json and also the website prevents me from pulling even i have added

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

code to pull the data , but no result:

```
 $.ajax(
    {
    // The link we are accessing.
    url: "http://horizon-websolutions.com",

    // The type of request.
    type: "get",

    // The type of data that is getting returned.
    dataType: "html",

    error: function(){
    alert("error");
    // Load the content in to the page.
    $("#output").html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
    },

    beforeSend: function(){
    alert("not yet"); },

    complete: function(){
    alert("done"); },

    success: function( strData ){
    alert("success");
    // Load the content in to the page.
    $("#output").html( strData );
    }
    }
    );

    // Prevent default click.
    return( false );
```

please help my telling the website accept my localhost request to pull data from the server . the same code tested on a pure php page and its working fine .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how secure this would be but one way to solve it is to enable CORS.

1. For Drupal 7 (would be analogous to Drupal 6) so you need to download and install the **CORS module**,
2. enable the module under **Modules**,
3. go to the **Drupal config** (**Configuration** on Drupal 7 main dashboard top navigator),
4. search for **CORS**. Click,
5. give the path for the links you wish to access. Examples are given on that page of how to put in new links.

Hope this helps.